# Launch4J - how to attach dependent jars to generated exe

Tags: java, jar, launch4j

I have a simple java project, which requires external jars.
I build this with netbeans and after Clean and Build command, I can find in dist directory the following structure:

```
-myApp.jar
-lib/
     library1.jar
     library2.jar
```

typical, I would say.

Now, I'd like to distribute myApp.jar with dependent libraries as one exe. 
Is this possible? I am trying to use Launch4J. In the GUI I create the config file, there are some options in *cp* section

```
<cp>lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar</cp>
```

but it seems to be classpath, and it is the only place I can refer to my extra jars.

After exe file is created, I can't find dependend libs in the exe (exe can be opened with winrar) and thus my application crashes.

How can I make the exe file properly then?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have experience of creating executable jar with Eclipse. the process is simple there.

Comment: Thanks, no chance to switch to Eclipse for me. It seems that I have to pack all my dependent jars into one jar and this will solve the issue.

Comment: you can do without switching to eclipse as well. Question is do you need executable like .exe or an executable jar will do. Its only the manifest file which points to the class needs to be executed. I remember this because when I was on this same question I had got some help in tuts. As you will notice having correct manifest file is what does the trick

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I definitely need an exe file not the jar.
In the meantime I found the link http://mavistechchannel.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/how-to-build-a-single-jar-file-with-external-libs/ which helped me building one jar with all dependent jars included. Once I got one jar, I got my Lanuch4J generated exe working fine.

Comment: yes that is a good work around. generate single working jar which includes all dependency and then generate executable exe with launch4j

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it often happens being unable to solve the problem I published it on StackOverflow ... and pretty soon after publishing the question I got an idea.

So the answer to my question is:

**Put all the dependent jars into one main jar.**

It took me some time to find info how can I do that.

To help people I decided to publish detailed instruction here - they are based on Netbeans 7.4.

1. Following article from http://mavistechchannel.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/how-to-build-a-single-jar-file-with-external-libs/ I created the ant script that build one-jar-app for me.
   I could then manually create exe via Launch4J
2. I then decided that I want more automated task, and I did that, Ant builds exe for me (via Launch4J)
3. Then I realized that I must do "clean and build" before my automated task (in point 2)/ I decided that I want clean and build to be done automatically before the exe build

Putting all together I am attaching my ant build script consisting of points 1,2,3:

It is required to edit build.xml and put the content found below before "project" end tag

```
<target name="package-for-launch4j" depends="clean,compile,jar">
    <property name="launch4jexe.dir" location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j" />
    <taskdef name="launch4j"
             classname="net.sf.launch4j.ant.Launch4jTask"
             classpath="${launch4jexe.dir}/launch4j.jar
            :${launch4jexe.dir}/lib/xstream.jar" />
    <property name="launch4j.jar.name" value="MyAppJarName"/>
    <property name="launch4j.dir" value="exe"/>
    <property name="launch4j.jar" value="${launch4j.dir}/${launch4j.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${launch4j.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${launch4j.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${launch4j.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${launch4j.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${launch4j.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${launch4j.dir}/temp_final.jar"
            excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${launch4j.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
    <launch4j configFile="misc/l4j-myapp.xml" />
</target>
```

then in Netbeans rightclick on the build.xml and choose:
Run Target / Other Targets / package-for-launch4j

exe file is ready in exe folder :-)

Comment: because it is a ant script it will work even for Eclipse or command line.

Comment: Nice to know. Also, in netbeans one can create shortcut (right click on ant target expanded in build.xml) so there is no need to go through Run Target / Other Targets / package-for-launch4j.

Answer (score 6):

When you are converting your .jar file

1. Go to classpath tab
2. Check custom classpath
3. On main class select your .jar from your dist folder after building the project
4. On the classpath textarea add your libraries, you add them right below that
   textarea writting the full path to the lib (of course including the
   lib, ie "C:\folder\lib\file.jar")

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

I have spent hours on this issue. So here is my contribution.

The problem here: how to sucessfully put your external jars that your .JAR program needs INSIDE the .exe that you generate.

We assume that you already, and correctly, configured the external jars on eclipse/netbeans and ALL WORK FINE with the command: java -jar yourprogram.jar.

So the real problem is how to ensure that this .EXE file will contain the external jars, otherwise it will not work properly.

1) First of all, you need to forget Launch4J and anyother program.

2) Install JSmooth, I recommend that you use the windows version.

3) On the left menu there is a button "Application". Click on it.

4) You will see a tab "Classpath" panel. Click on the plus (+) and add your external .jar's files. And that is it!!

Don't forget to put your .jar application marking checkbox "use am embedded jar" and choose the main class properly. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue while migrating my .jar to exe. I also had many dependent libraries as well. So These were the steps I performed :

1. Download and Install launch4j.
2. Open your project in netbeans. Clean and build the project.
3. Make sure you have a folder named 'dist' in the project directory. It will have your jar files with lib folder(containing the dependent libraries).
4. Open launch 4j.
5. Create output file in the dist folder. For example : OutputFile : D:******\My_App\dist\my_application.exe
6. Browse your jar file in the next row. For example : Jar : D:******\My_App\dist\my_application.jar
7. Go to classpath tab. Tick CustomClasspath. Press browse icon, and browse to your jar file which is located in the dist folder.
8. Specify Min Jre version in the JRE tab.
9. Save the configration.
10. Build the wrapper(by clicking the settings icon)
11. Your exe file will be generated in the dist folder.
    Thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting different links of places which had helped me

> [How to include all dependent Jars within a single non-executable jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083151/how-to-include-all-dependent-jars-within-a-single-non-executable-jar)
>
> [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)
>
> http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

and most importantly

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

quick tut

> http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-add-your-manifest-into-a-jar-file/

Answer (score 0):

To include external libraries with Launch4j you have to have the ".jar" files of the external libraries near your .exe (mine are just in the same folder) then in "Classpath" you put in the path to the .jar files into "Edit Item: "

Answer (score 0):

In launch4j go to the classpath tab. Tick the custom classpath field. In the edit field, enter the full path of each jar you want included and press accept. When finished type just the name of the main class into the separate field (ie MyProg). All the jars will now be included in the exe.

PS I have all the jars in the same directory. I'm using version 3.12