# Launch4j - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException

Tags: java, installation

I used launch4j (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) software to create an executable of my application created in java netbeans.

I did everything as I saw in a tutorial, just that when I run the exectutavel it creates in my application, it gives this error:

[image]

The message shown below is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Does anyone can help me solve this problem please.

I've been searching but I can not solve. I apologize for this question but am new to java.

Thank you all.

Greetings

Comment: did you bundled Java mail jar with application?

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your launch4j configuration file add the jars like this

```
<classPath mainClass="your.main.class">
    <cp>path/to/javamail.jar</cp>
    <cp>path/to/folder/*.jar</cp> // you can also add all the jars in a folder like this
</classPath>
```

It will automatically bundle them.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

Just went through netbeans integration with launch4j and it seems there is no way to write your on config xml file instead it prompts you in launch4J GUI for dependencies. I searched and found [this Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917960/launch4j-how-to-attach-dependent-jars-to-generated-exe). This is what you want. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code that you kindly provided. But where do I insert this code?

Comment: In your launch4j configuration file that you used to create executable

Comment: But the file is a .Jar :S

Comment: launch4j.jar is separate then the configuration file that is an xml where you configured all the things related to creation of executables

Comment: I add this: Class-Path: lib/mail.jar         on manifest.mf, but gives me the same error...

Comment: Are you creating exe or not ?

Comment: Then search and find launch4j xml config file and entery there

Comment: This does not exist. Did you mean Build.xml?

Comment: just edited answer .. please go through the link in it

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's really help. It works, but only appears the first form login. then gives this error: ja.null.pointer.Exception you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Add Java mail jar to classpath.

Download it from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR

Comment: Thanks for reply. how can I Add Java mail jar to classpath? Sorry for question, but i'm new at programming java...

Comment: One way is, from you Eclipse project right click > Properties > java Build path. And in Libraries tab click Add external jars and add this jar from your hard disk location.

Comment: There will some thing equivalent.