# java .jar file convert to .exe file

Tags: java, launch4j

I use launch4j to convert jar file to the exe file in Windows XP.
 
After I build wrapper, I go to test the wrapper. 
However, it shows ""Error : A JNI error has occurred ,please check your installation and try again" and "A Java Exception has occured".

Below is the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

What does the errors say? How should I do?

Comment: which IDE-eclipse,netbeans..- are you using?

Comment: I am using netbeans 7.4

Comment: Is it working when running from netbeans? If so, you probably didn't add external jars to the exe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917960/launch4j-how-to-attach-dependent-jars-to-generated-exe

Comment: In netbeans, it runs.

Comment: You need to make sure that the jar libraries your application relies on are also included.  I don't know if launch4j can do that or not

Comment: @MadProgrammer launch4j can support multiple jar files?

Comment: @MichaelKuan it all depends, is it just a light entry point, which then executes the jar file or does it act as a wrapper, wrap the jar files into a single file? If it's a wrapper, then you need to include all the jar files and launch4j needs to know about it so it can do its thing...

Comment: @MichaelKuan did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a jar that contains the class

```
  JXDatePicker
```

This is where you can get it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx094jar.html

Add it in the libraries, and link the path..It must not give this error.

Comment: If you're going to link to things, at least link to the [latest](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

Comment: @MadProgrammer edit it so that it can be useful for whosoever uses it.