# Running project in netbeans doesn't recreate the jar

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar

I'm having this strange problem that just started recently, and I can't figure out what I did to mess it up.

Basically, though my files are actually compiling every time I press save, when I press run, it doesn't notice that the files were changed, and it just uses the same jar that was there before, without updating from my changed code. The only thing I can do to notice that I changed the code is to clean and build, which of course takes a very long time and slows down my development.

I use git, and I added a target for launch4j ([Launch4J - how to attach dependent jars to generated exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917960)), but it was working since then and changing back my build.xml didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Mysterious.

I still don't know what got Netbeans into this unstable state, but I realized that I haven't exited Netbeans in several days, so I restarted the program and now it works fine.