# classpath & Derby jars

Tags: java, jar, derby, launch4j

With Linux ; Application Directory is :

/home/momy/A1/specter/

```
|
- - → src/
      |
      - - → specterMain/
        |
        - - → MainClass.java
- - → lib/
      |
      - - → derby.jar
      - - → derbyclient.jar
```

i) to add all derby jar files to classpath  :

java -classpath /home/momy/A1/specter/lib/* src.specterMain.MainClass

I get this :
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.momy.A1.specter.lib.derbyclient.jar

ii) to set the classpath

java -classpath /home/momy/A1/specter src.specterMain.MainClass

I get this error :
Error: Could not find or load main class src.specterSafeMain.MainClass

on netbeans the application works fine….
I repackage the application to .exe version,the .exe start works but DB not work shows that the derby jars should be included in classpath .
Any ideas :)

Comment: [This might be a good start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917960/launch4j-how-to-attach-dependent-jars-to-generated-exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the path to the classes, but not to the sources.

Where does Netbeans produce the files with fileending *.class ? Add this directory to the classpath:

```
java -cp bin:lib/derby.jar:lib/derbyclient.jar specterMain.MainClass
```

Comment: the MainClass.class file in this path :  /home/momy/A1/specter/bin/specterMain/MainClass.class ....... so I did this ; java -cp /home/momy/A1/specter  bin.specterMain.MainClass     .....got same error that class not found !!!

Comment: The "bin" is a directory and not a package! Put it in the classpath.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, so that i receive the points?