# Is it possible to get IntelliJ IDEA to generate an executable JAR manifest like Eclipse does?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar

I've had to make some modifications to an old Java-based project which contains dependent JAR files in the project tree. When I last worked on this project 3 years ago, I was developing it in Eclipse and generating runnable JAR files using Eclipse's `File -> Export...` function, which worked great.

When I started working on this project again I switched to using IDEA. Following online documentation I was able to create a runnable jar using IDEA's `Project Structure -> Artifacts` pane.

However, I encountered several problems when trying to use the JAR file IDEA generates that I didn't encounter when using the one generated by Eclipse:

- If I tried extracting the dependent JARs directly into my runnable JAR, I would get [Java security exceptions about invalid signature files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) as the RSA/SF manifest files from my dependent JARs were getting extracted.
- If I tried to embed the dependent JARs within my generated JAR file rather than extracting the class files from them, I encountered "class not found" exceptions.

To understand what was happening, I tried generating the JAR file using Eclipse as I'd done previously, which worked great. The difference seemed to be that IDEA was packing in a manifest file stored in my project tree like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.<company>.main.Main
```

In contrast, Eclipse was generating the manifest file during the export process, which looked like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.<company>.main.Main

Name: com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout$LayoutInfo.class
SHA1-Digest: J6yu1IuQZO0rgeF7Enl4p7u4ykU=

Name: com/jgoodies/forms/builder/ButtonBarBuilder.class
SHA1-Digest: 7ApcSFXKq2rw8IRkIl+R7y2rzIA=

Name: com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout$ComponentSizeCache.class
SHA1-Digest: cUMTPR0lwBEeQVUd3tsCFq6cMhA=

Name: com/jgoodies/forms/util/Utilities.class
SHA1-Digest: UbvvkJcHLyNbduyo07Hr2bSz06E=

...
```

It also excluded the RSA/SF files from the signed dependent JARs so that I didn't get any security exceptions when running the generated JAR.

My question is: is it possible to get IDEA to generate a manifest file similarly to how Eclipse does?

Comment: No: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150485.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. That's a shame.

Comment: Linked jars should work, but not the single jar, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 (second example).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Unfortunately I need a single JAR as I later convert it into an executable using launch4j. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19919577/1636276

Comment: In this case you can use maven-assembly-plugin or Gradle FatJar or custom Ant task.

Comment: Also, launch4j doesn't require all the dependencies to be in the single jar.

Comment: That could work - if I need to do significant more work on this project in the future, I'll look into getting a proper build process involving these tools set up.