# IntelliJ IDEA - JAR Manifest.MF incomplete, JAR with eclipse working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I am trying to create a runnable JAR File with IntelliJ.
I followed this tutorial: [Quickly create Jar artifact for application](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)
I have a lot of 3rd party libraries included.

Unfortunatelly I got the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

I created a JAR from the same project with Eclipse and everything was the same except the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

MANIFEST.MF in IntelliJ JAR:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.continental.ref.REFController
```

MANIFEST.MF in Eclipse JAR:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.continental.ref.REFController

Name: org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractLinkedMap$LinkMapIter
 ator.class
SHA1-Digest: +GMX4XDNU3rbmKNHyTmYDlZT44Q=

Name: org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/SqlTimeConverter.class
SHA1-Digest: kKXUmTycgy5F07EuojB2tsz9424=

Name: org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/TreeBidiMap$Node.class
SHA1-Digest: g1+1ao8G8CPfvRmMi61ThauUVGU=

Name: org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/TransformingComparato
 r.class
SHA1-Digest: bd4hdiKvX/OSymUta0Tv5ucbwDQ=
...
```

I really do not have any IDEA how to force IntelliJ to calculate hashes of the libraries.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I also tried not to extract JAR files into the new JAR, in this case the MANIFEST.MF is the same but my code dies with ClassDefNotFoundError.

Comment: What Intellij version do you have?

Comment: 2017.2.5 - Community Edition

Comment: Have you checked this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly

Comment: It has the link to the same guide. But the answer itself has steps for actual versions. Have you followed them?

Comment: I f it still doesn't work, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746177/how-do-i-create-a-runnable-jar-in-intellij-as-i-would-in-eclipse/43855741#43855741

Comment: How can I "add it as a dependency in the manifest file"? As the answer says.

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901370/7147393 ?

Comment: No, this one is not working, I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855741/5877561

Comment: @Levente see the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44283408/104891